# PHP SoapClient->__doRequest

Tags: php, soap-client

I need to test some XML requests manually, i.e. I want to call a webservice method with an XML request previously created.
I'm trying to use the SoapClient __doRequest, and all I get back is a blank, empty response.

I already read the documentation, and several other posts here and seems no one has tried this before and the few who asked similar question, got really no response.

Again, the reason of doing it this way it's just a way to test an XMLRequest generated by other tool that is causing problems at certain webservice.
So, I can't call the soapclient generated methods, nor I can't call "_call".
I need to send my own previously created XML request using SOAPClient.
Is this possible? If so how....

```
$result = $soapClient->__doRequest($docRequest, "http://someservice.asmx", "http://someservice/Login",  soap_1_2, 0);
```

When I call this I get null at $result without any error.

Comment: I think some problem on your "location" parameter.

Comment: "XMLRequest generated by other tool" - is this the one in `$docRequest`?

Comment: To get a soap response you must use $client->__getLastResponse(); (and or $client->__getLastResponseHeaders ();)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from http://php.net/manual/soapclient.dorequest.php

Maybe your call throws an exception you need to catch:

```php
$exception = null; 
$result = parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way); 
if((isset($this->__soap_fault)) && ($this->__soap_fault != null)) { 
        //this is where the exception from __doRequest is stored 
        $exception = $this->__soap_fault; 
} 

if($exception != null) { 
        throw $exception; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to do it like this:

```
class LocalSoapClient extends SoapClient
{
    function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0) 
    {
        $request = "...."; // your changed XML goes here

        return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
    }
}

$client = new LocalSoapClient($wsdl_url, array('trace' => 1));
$client->__soapCall($function_name, array($service_call_params));
```

Note that you don't call __doRequest directly - this gets executed when you do the standard __soapCall.